# Healthcheck is failing when deploying a mssql database

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

The healthcheck is failing when deploying a mssql database on AWS ECS.

Below is a copy of the service form the docker-compose.yml file

```
  sql_server_db:
    image: 'mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest'
    environment:
        SA_PASSWORD: Password123@
        ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=false
    deploy:
        resources:
            limits:
              cpus: '1'
              memory: 8Gb
            reservations:
              cpus: '0.5'
              memory: 4GB
    healthcheck:
      test: ["/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd", "-U", "sa", "-P", "Password123@", "-Q", "SELECT 1"]
      interval: 1m
      retries: 10
      start_period: 60s
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue, when checking the "inspect" for the container I was getting "Login fails for SA"

this was disturbing because the password was the same (I used the .env variable) ... but for some reason the special characters seems to mess up the check.

I simply created a oneliner script

```
/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P $SA_PASSWORD -Q "Select 1"
```

and then I called it as HC

```
healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD","bash","/healthcheck.sh", ]
```

and it works

I don't really like it but I will keep it until I find a better one (I am not sure it can actually fails )

Comment: I'll take another look at the original problem and try your method . I ended up removing the exposed ports and the need for a healthcheck for the time being